# How to switch 2 values in a List

Tags: c#, generic-list

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. The purpose of this code is 
to change the places of two values in a sequence.

When i type in console Switch 78 97 it does the job well but the other way around it's not working: **Switch 97 78**

this is the full code

```
static void Main()
{
    List<int> numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ").Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToList();
    string command;
    while((command = Console.ReadLine())!= "END")
    {
        string[] execute = command.Split();
        string type = execute[0];
        switch (type)
        {
            case "Change":
                int firstNumber = int.Parse(execute[1]);
                int secoundNumber = int.Parse(execute[2]);
                ChangeNumber(firstNumber, secoundNumber, ref numbers);
                    break;
            case "Hide":
                HideNumber(ref numbers, execute);
                    break;
            case "Switch":
                SwitchNumber(ref numbers, execute);
                    break;
            case "Insert":
                InsertNumber(ref numbers, execute);
                    break;
            case "Reverse":
                Reverse(ref numbers, execute);
                break;
        }
    }
    foreach (var item in numbers)
    {
        Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
}

//Switch {paintingNumber} {paintingNumber2} – find the given paintings in the collections 
//if they exist and switch their places.
static void SwitchNumber(ref List<int> numbers, string[] execute)
{
    if (numbers.Contains(int.Parse(execute[1])) && numbers.Contains(int.Parse(execute[2])))
    {
        int paintingNumber1 = int.Parse(execute[1]); // 97
        int paintingNumber2 = int.Parse(execute[2]); // 78
        int temp = int.Parse(execute[1]); // 97
        numbers[numbers.IndexOf(paintingNumber1)] = paintingNumber2; // 5 =  78
        numbers[numbers.IndexOf(paintingNumber2)] = temp; // 6 = 97
    }
}
```

Comment: `int.Parse(execute[1])` There is no need to run that four times. Run it once, and assign to a variable and use that variable.

Comment: Do **both of** the two `IndexOf` calls **before** the `[]` calls. The problem is your second `IndexOf` call is finding the value you just stuck in `execute[1]`'s index, not `execute[2]`'s index.

Comment: Also `ref List<int>` is [pretty pointless](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

Comment: Fromt the documentation of `List<T>.IndexOf`: "Returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a value in the List<T> or in a portion of it."(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netcore-2.2). Note here it finds the first occurrence. Once you change the first value if that value is earlier in the list it'll return that index for the second change (effectively reverting the change)

Comment: There are so many issues with design like that. If you happen to fix the original (logical) issue, try answering these questions: `1.` What happens when user enters less than two args in `Switch` command? `2.` What happens if there are more than two args? `3.` What if args aren't integer numbers? `4.` What if numbers enetered aren't in the list? `5`. What if user types lower-case switch? ... I could go on.

Comment: Did you try Mong's solution below? _Which is the same as what I suggested above._

Comment: @PeterWolf, it is pretty pointless in this code sample, but it is ok to use `ref` keyword with reference types. For example, you may create a new `List<int>` in `SwitchNumber()` and assign it to `numbers` variable defined upper.

Comment: did you change your mind about the solution? didn't it solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that after this call:

```
numbers[numbers.IndexOf(int.Parse(execute[1]))] = paintingNumber2; // 5 =  78
```

you practically moved the second number to the position of the first. If you now try to find the index of the second number you get the one of the first:

[image]

and then you overwrite the wrong value and end up at your initial conditions

Solution: You need to grab the indices before any manipulation of the list begins:

```
int index_1 = numbers.IndexOf(paintingNumber1));
int index_2 = numbers.IndexOf(paintingNumber2);
numbers[index_1] = paintingNumber2; // 5 =  78
numbers[index_2] = paintingNumber1; // 6 = 97
```